# what does roslib.load_manifest() do?

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('pr2_pick_and_place_demos').
```

this is one part of a python file. i do not know the meaning of `roslib.load_manifest('pr2_pick_and_place_demos')`.someone to tell me .TA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115346/what-does-roslib.load_manifest()-do?/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-07**:
Please provide more details to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslib.load_manifest()` reads the package manifest and sets up the python library path based on the package dependencies. It's required for older rosbuild-based packages, but is no longer needed on catkin.

The rosbuild version of the [Python Publisher and Subscriber Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) explains it in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13